# Why is '+' Character Removed From Url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Why does Mvc remove `+` from  `code=wamTEpI6kZcP997j2d+ZeQ==`

**link**

```
http://localhost:33693/PasswordRecovery/InitPassword?email=abc@gmail.com&code=wamTEpI6kZcP997j2d+ZeQ==
```

**Controller Func**

```
public ActionResult InitPassword(string email, string code)
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: You need to URI encode the `+`.  Use `%2B` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Th `'+'` sign has a special meaning in URLs, it means 'space'.

You should UrlEncode the code parameter to preserve the '+' sign.

You can use `@Uri.EscapeDataString()` or `@Html.Raw()` in your Razor views.

Comment: Strictly, `+` is only specified as meaning a space in a query portion, but that is the case anyway and some system treat it that way elsewhere.